# How to access sys.stderr after calling PyErr_Print with python c-api

Tags: c#, python, python-c-api

I am trying to use the python c-api from a c# project via dll import.

I am getting an `ModuleNotFoundError` when importing some modules, which I thought are builtin. 
(Note: I compiled python myself)

I am a bit stuck right now, but my hope is to get some extra information when calling `PyErr_Print()` in the code below.

**Code:**

```
IntPtr modulePtr = NativeInterface.PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx(moduleName,compiledModule, path);
if (modulePtr == IntPtr.Zero)
{
  NativeInterface.PyErr_Print();
  PythonException exception = PythonException.Query();
  throw exception;
}
```

The docs for [PyErr_Print](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/exceptions.html?highlight=pyerr_print#c.PyErr_Print) state that it will populate `sys.stderr` with some error information. 
What would be the easiest way to read this variable from my c# application?

Comment: I don't know enough C# to really make this an answer but i'd do something like: 1) replace `sys.stdout` with a `BytesIO` object. 2) Get the contents of that `BytesIO` object with `PyBytes_AsString`. Both steps are a little more involved than I've made out, but you can probably write that code in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer gives C code because I understand C and not C#, but I think it should be pretty transferable.

By default `sys.stderr` writes to some console somewhere and so you can't meaningfully try to read from it. However, it's perfectly possible to replace it to redirect the output. Two sensible options include writing to a file, and writing to a `StringIO` object that can later be queried.

The C code to run is basically equivalent to:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO # Python 3
sys.stderr = StringIO()
```

or in C:

```
int setup_stderr() {
    PyObject *io = NULL, *stringio = NULL, *stringioinstance = NULL;

    int success = 0;

    io = PyImport_ImportModule("io");
    if (!io) goto done;
    stringio = PyObject_GetAttrString(io,"StringIO");
    if (!stringio) goto done;
    stringioinstance = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(stringio,NULL);
    if (!stringioinstance) goto done;

    if (PySys_SetObject("stderr",stringioinstance)==-1) goto done;

    success = 1;

    done:
    Py_XDECREF(stringioinstance);
    Py_XDECREF(stringio);
    Py_XDECREF(io);
    return success;
}
```

You run this once at the start of your program.

To query the contents of `sys.stderr` you'd then do the equivalent of:

```
value = sys.stderr.getvalue()
encoded_value = value.encode() # or you could just handle the unicode output
```

In C:

```
char* get_stderr_text() {
    PyObject* stderr = PySys_GetObject("stderr"); // borrowed reference

    PyObject *value = NULL, *encoded = NULL;

    char* result = NULL;
    char* temp_result = NULL;
    Py_ssize_t size = 0;

    value =  PyObject_CallMethod(stderr,"getvalue",NULL);
    if (!value) goto done;
    // ideally should get the preferred encoding
    encoded = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(value,"utf-8","strict");
    if (!encoded) goto done;
    if (PyBytes_AsStringAndSize(encoded,&temp_result,&size) == -1) goto done;
    size += 1;

    // copy so we own the memory
    result = malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i) {
        result[i] = temp_result[i];
    }

    done:
    Py_XDECREF(encoded);
    Py_XDECREF(value);

    return result;

}
```

There's a bit of effort spent copying the string. You might consider working directly with unicode and using [`PyUnicode_AsUCS4Copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUCS4Copy).

You probably then want to look at clearing the string after you've written it, just done by replacing `sys.stderr` with a fresh `StringIO` object.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer. I solved my problem by adopting the python script I called via C-API. However my original question was, how to solve this using the C-API. Therefore I think it's preferable to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to acces `sys.stderr` via C-Api. But I realized that I can run python scripts via the c-api (See [PyRun_String](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_String) in the docs).
So I am debugging now by writing sys.path to a textfile.

```
import sys
file = open('log.txt','w')
for path in sys.path:
    file.write(i+'\n')
```